# Minimum tab width in Firefox Quantum

Tags: firefox, tabs, about-config, firefox-quantum

Firefox Quantum changed the minimum width of Tabs, previous versions of Firefox had it set to a greater value.

(**minimum tab width* - when you have a lot of open tabs they shrink to some predefined minimum width).

How do I increase this predefined minimum tab width?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can increase the tab min width by using advanced settings in **about:config**:

1. enter `about:config` in URL bar
2. click the "*I accept the risk*" button
3. use the search box to search for `browser.tabs.tabMinWidth`
4. double-click the item and set a new value

Comment: doesn't work in latest versions :(